# Excel VBA - Web Server Authentication popup

Tags: asp.net, vba, excel

I am trying to query into my spreadsheet a web relay device (ControlByWeb X310)[X310](http://www.controlbyweb.com/x310/x-310_users_manual.pdf) basically a IoT device.  It has a built-in web servver and when I manually browse its URL for the first time it pops up with a web server login page (not a browser HTML window):

[image]

I've recorded a macro of adding this log data via an Excel insert "from Web" data connection.  It basically uses recorded the following VBA:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://111.111.111.111:8080/log.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))....
```

Within the last item end With statement ".Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False" takes a while to do it's thing but returns nothing. If I've previously manually logged into the web page via my edge browser and authenticated access, then this command returns exactly what I need.  I have thousands of these devices sitting on the internet that I need to collect data from so a script that will loop through each would be very practical.

Is there a command or syntax for the QueryTables object that can pass a user id and password to the login pop-up?  Something like:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://111.111.111.111:8080/log.txt", ID:="name", PWD:="password"
```

... does not work.

I've searched high and low and found a lot of info on login by scraping HTML but the pop-up I get is being service up by the web server authentication. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the [X310 manual](http://www.controlbyweb.com/x310/x-310_users_manual.pdf) (PDF) you linked above (page 115) - "Note: If the Control Password is enabled in the setup pages, the password will be required to access the log file" Can you disable the control password (and thus not need to worry about authentication) or do you require to have that password in place?

Comment: See page 95 of that same manual, which describes how to pass the username/password (as a base-64-encoded version of username:password)